# [VC/MFC]why the app window is affected by other items which move across it?

Tags: windows, visual-c++, mfc

I've made two screen shots in order to make the problem specified.

`The normal style:`

[image: normal style]

`the affected style after I move some windows such as browsers across it:`

[image]

I wonder why this happened?And How can fix this problem?I'm working with VS2008 on Windows.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I solve this by redrawing the  window when it is activated.But still not be perfect cuz it may keep messing if window is not activated.

Answer (score 1):

When this has happened to me - it's due to not handling the OnPaint calls correctly. That's the area I would look at